# Images are not uploading in Godaddy

Tags: php, cpanel, image-uploading

Some specific photos with size lower than 1MB are not uploading in `godaddy` and becomes `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. I think this is an unsolved question as of yet. I don't think there is anything different about the image. It's the same file type and was taken on the same day by the same camera with the same dimensions and DPI.

I don't know much about it since I don't have much experience in using `cpanel`. I think there is some problem with my `.ini` file. I named it as `php.ini` inside root folder.

Here is my `.ini` file:

```
memory_limit=500M
post_max_size=500M
upload_max_filesize=500M
max_file_uploads = 3000
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: infact I just used this ini text and apply at my server. It worked. Now I can upload all my files. Wasted two days to find this crucial info . Thanks buddy for capturing here.

Answer (score 0):

**Probable Solution 1:**

Why are you setting your max_file_uploads so high? Is this line okie with your php.ini file:

```
; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.

; http://php.net/file-uploads

file_uploads = On
```

**Probable Solution 2:**

Did you restart your apache2 server after you configure php.ini file?

**In linux:**

`sudo service apache2 restart`
or just restart your XAMPP or WAMP or whatever?

**Probable Solution 3:**

Check your connection with your Server (First Priority). Why connection is resetting?

Comment: i have to restart my apache server in godaddy?

Comment: email godaddy customer care